# Is the format of (P)SFTP's dir/ls standard?

Tags: directory, sftp, putty, directory-listing

I'm putting together something to download some files over SFTP.  I'm using PuTTY's `psftp.exe` command.

When I do a `dir`/`ls` in PSFTP, is the format of the output standardized, either by SFTP or by PSFTP itself?  Or is it just whatever free-form text the server happens to send in response?

I ask because I believe in FTP (way back when!), it was not at all standardized, and I only have one SFTP server here to test against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Unlike FTP (which used text `LIST` output), the SFTP protocol is based on binary structures, so Putty is doing all the formatting.  Specifically, it uses the [SSH_FXP_READDIR](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-8.2.2) command to read directory entries, which are returned in the format specified by [SSH_FXP_NAME](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-9.4).</s>

Ideally you would use an API, rather than psftp.  But if you choose to parse the text, you have PuTTY and only PuTTY to worry about.

My mistake.  [The newer draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-9.4) I looked at does not have such a text `longname` field.  However, [older versions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02#page-22) do.

Comment: This is NOT true. In SFTP-3 (that PSFTP uses) and older, the `SSH_FXP_NAME` contains `longname` field that includes formatted listing entry. PSFTP prints that. So the format WILL differ with server.

Answer (score 2):

Matthew, the local client may choose to show the information on the *longname* slots from the *SSH_FXP_NAME* response instead of generating it locally from the *filename* and *attrs* slots.

Whit out looking at how psftp does it internally, you can not be completely sure that its format will not change when connecting to a different server.

Comment: This is correct answer. PSFTP prints the `longname` field of `SSH_FXP_NAME` coming from the server. So format WILL definitely differ with server.